# I am unable to comeout of the forloop in the following code evenif the IF statement is successful

Tags: batch-file

I am unable to come out of the for loop in the following code even if the IF statement is successful. The present scenario is the code is going through the 'for loop' completely and not moving to :next if the if statement is successful. I don't know what to do?

```
FOR %%A IN (2,3,4) DO GOTO %%A

:2
echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-2^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

:3
echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-3^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

:4
echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-4^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

:NEXT 
ECHO ^<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=1^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=1 COLOR="#808080"^>^<P^>%ydate2%^</FONT^>^</TD^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=1^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=1 COLOR="#808080"^>^<P^>%CDate%^</FONT^>^</TD^>>>c.html
GOTO END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with the `for` loop but you don't really need it. The `if`'s provide all the flow control you need.

```
REM Starts here
echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-2^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

REM If file doesn't exist fall over to here, same with the others
echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-3^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

echo wscript.echo ^(Date^(^)-4^)>yesterday.vbs
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo yesterday.vbs') do set ydate1=%%a
del yesterday.vbs
set ydate1=%ydate1:/=%
set m=%ydate1:~0,2%
set d=%ydate1:~2,2%
set y=%ydate1:~4,4%
set ydate2=%m%-%d%-%y%
echo yesterday was %ydate2%
IF EXIST ATELBSNT40_complete_txs_%ydate2%.log GOTO :NEXT

:NEXT 
ECHO ^<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=1^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=1 COLOR="#808080"^>^<P^>%ydate2%^</FONT^>^</TD^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<TD WIDTH="25%" VALIGN="TOP" HEIGHT=1^>>>c.html
ECHO ^<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=1 COLOR="#808080"^>^<P^>%CDate%^</FONT^>^</TD^>>>c.html
GOTO END
```

Comment: well yes thats true. didnt click me at all...thanks for your help :D

Comment: No prob, if this answered your question you should click the tick on it to show this as accepted.